# 50AMP cord from generator into sub panel

Tags: electrical, subpanel, generator

My sub panel, located in the garage, does not have a main breaker.  The main panel, located on the outside of the house, has a main breaker.  The CB's in the main panel are as follows: Dryer, Subfeed, A/C, Furnace.

I installed a 50AMP CB in the sub panel wired to a 50AMP plug to my generator.  My thought was that this would power the main panel as well but it did not. WHY? As an example my A/C is not operational.

I'm not asking for info about an interlock device or transfer switch or state codes.  I'm simply asking why there is no power going to the main panel.

Comment: So just to be clear, when you write "wired to a 50AMP plug to my generator", do you mean you wired up a [Suicide Cable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suicide_cable)?

Comment: You've said nothing about how the main and secondary panels are connected. I'm guessing that the breaker between them is open. I'm also guessing, given your setting aside the question of transfer switch, that you might have destroyed your generator if it wasn't.

Comment: As long as you know this is a big no-no/illegal, was both breakers on? In the main and sub panel.  Did you have any power going into the sub panel circuits?

Comment: @keshlam   Here's hoping OP was smart enough to turn off the main breaker first.

Comment: brhans
I am not using a suicide cable. The cable is wired directly into a 50AMP CB and the other end is wired to a 14-50P. 

keshlam
The main panel is wired to the sub panel by two hots and a neutral. My generator is fine. 
 
crip659
I understand. I'm simply asking the question. Yes my whole sub panel has power. I can power the whole house. The AC is not working. (AC is in main panel).  Yes the main breaker is off. I just have a question as to the main panel not being powered.

Comment: crip659 and as noted the sub panel does not have a main breaker only the main panel does.  The main breaker was turned off first. All breakers were turned off in main panel and sub panel. Generator was plugged in, turned on, and 50AMP CB closed . Then other CBs were closed to operate certain house hold items.  That is when I discovered the AC was not working. I checked the main panel and confirmed there was no power to the main panel.

Comment: Wiring diagram please.  And if you have a male connector on the end of a cable that will be live for any possible combination of switch positions - that is a suicide cable.  I’m hoping your diagram will show that we’re misinterpreting your words  and our concern misplaced.

Comment: MadMonty I appreciate the concern. I really do. That aside, all I am asking is if it possible to power a main panel through the sub panel without adding a dedicated CB to each where the dedicated CB in the sub feeds the dedicated CB in the main.

Comment: If everything is on except the main breaker, you should get power in the main panel.  One reason for all the safeties when powering from a generator so you do not feed power to power line workers.  Electricity does not care which direction it flows.

Comment: crip659 then what are the potential reasons there is no power to the main panel

Comment: Open breaker. Open connection

Answer (score 1):

Open breaker. Open connection. Erroneous measurement. The device you're concerned about doesn't like the voltage or waveform the generator is supplying.

Pick one and track it down step by step with a meter. If that one doesn't pan out try the next. And the next. Without having our hands on the system I don't think we can say much more than that.

Comment: keshlam-I found this answer in a previous thread: "you can't have a generator feeding a subpanel feeding the main The only thing a correctly wired generator input on a subpanel can feed is loads on that sub-panel. you either need an input for the generator at the main, or you need an entirely separate set of wires from the generator location to the main You'd need to feed the generator power DIRECTLY to a dedicated breaker if you want to power another panel, you'd need to install a dedicated breaker in the first panel and feed that to another dedicated breaker" This is a source of my confusion

Comment: I've also read in other threads the same that it is not possible to provide power to the main panel if the dedicated CB for the generator is located in the sub panel

Comment: Without knowing exactly how you have wired this all, and exactly what the configuration was when you tested it, I can't guess further. We just don't have the data.

Comment: Re providing power from sub panel to main panel: That's the transfer/interlock issue. You need to guarantee generator can never be connected at same time as mains. That's relatively easy if the generator connects at the highest panel affected, unreasonably difficult if you want to back-feed.